# Mock server for React learning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rest, server, react-redux

I'm learning React recently. The problem is, in learning React and redux I have to run a server in the background. I don't want to spend time building a REST API for now. So, can anyone suggest me with some mock server where I can find some JSON data for showing it in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fake REST APIs List** that we can use to mock out our back end for prototypes

- [jsonPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)
- [Fake jSON](https://fakejson.com/)
- [Mocky](https://designer.mocky.io/)
- [Fake Rest](https://fake.rest/)
- [Beeceptor](https://beeceptor.com/)

Guys everyone is welcome to edit and add more in the **LIST**

Answer (score 1):

Postman also lets you create a mock server for testing you APIs. It has an extensive documentation.

Comment: I tried mock server but you can make only 1000 mock request in free plan.  Consider the price